# Is it possible to instantiate html/js template in a new tab inside a html document

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, knockout.js

I have a html table which is doing some calculations with some jQuery/knockout.js behind it.

the raw outline in my head is to pack this "content" into a template and load one instance of it on the load event. This instance would be in a simple tabbed container inside the window.

When the user clicks a button a second tab should be created with another instance of this template.

How can this be done the most efficent way? Especcialy how can I store my unique html/js code in a reusable template to be instantiated.

I am imagining a snippet which looks something along those lines:

```
var tabCounter = 0;
var divID = "tabNr";

$("body").on("click","a.newTab",function(){
    tabCounter++; 
    var tabbedContent = $("<div class="tab" id="'" + divID + tabCounter + "'"></div>");
    tabbedContent.html('insert whole html block from template here which references the   knockout viewmodel --- how?');
    return false;
})
```

Any help is appreciated

Comment: You can insert the plain html content with knockout bindings, like `<div data-bind="text: value"></div>`, then call apply bindings `ko.applyBindings(viewModel, $("#" + divID")[0]);`. For each new tab you click, create a new ViewModel object with the properties you need.

Answer (score 0):

My method would be to have an `observableArray` in your viewmodel representing the tabs. Each object in this array would represent the data for the table in each tab.

This array can start off with just one element in it which would put you in the situation you're in now. But if simply add an element to the array, Knockout can render the html needed for the next tab.

Therefore, you can avoid inserting html strings into the DOM via jQuery, which is what Knockout is for in the first place.

Note: If you are using a JavaScript framework to enhance your tabs, you may need a custom binding to call the frameworks method.

Comment: what about creating a second viewmodel explicitly for the tabs and the inserted html. So the Viewmodel would contain a Viewmodel.
If I just insert an ko.observableArray into my VM every tab would get its own observable array with data for the tabs.

Comment: Essentially, a Viewmodel is just an object (as is everything in javascript). So, yes: you can think of it as a `TabViewmodel`.

Comment: I haven't had time to pülay this through. Still on my to-do-list. If it works this way (and I'm not too stupid to work it through) I'll mark your post as an answer and upvote it. 
Will take some time though ...